# How can I change the NAN column name with other cell on the base of condition

Tags: pandas, numpy

[here table](https://github.com/demirez/math-for-machine-learning/blob/dc7b590f8b45abe21e1da0fa2bf2f2ab386ae93b/1_log/dftable.xlsx) [This is DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF0cK.png)

I add df from excel, its a messy, there are merge, I need exact row number as data saved in excel row because there are some other information which refer as excel row, what I am trying to do that row 16 and 17 include column name, I assign df.columns = df.iloc[16] and as expected there are some NaN column name so I would like to change them with df.iloc[17].

In general how I can use NaN in if statement and how to tell that where is NaN get value from lower cell on the base of location to NaN.(Please consider that also this NaN located in column name so replaced value will be assigned as column name.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @arkhe a reproducible sample means code that can be used to generate the dataframe in your screenshot. If not, you can add a file of your excel onto here,

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your dataframe is named `df`, you can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.columns`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) to rename your columns with an `if` statement to check if the column name matches the string `nan` :

```
df.columns = [df[c].iloc[0] if c.lower() == 'nan' else c for c in df.columns]
```

##### `>>> print(df)`

[image]

Comment: It didn't work, says that 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'.

Comment: Your real dataframe doesn't match to the first example you gave. Also, the photo doesn't show the headers (columns names). You have to share a reproducible example so the community can help you.

Comment: You are right, ok so now I add real df, there is no lower case NaN (I mistakenly show in first df) I want to write that if this is NaN for this cell go and take value from down cell.

Comment: You still didn't gave a reproducible sample of your df (as text and not a screenshot) though.

Comment: I add link, that excel file similar which I try.

Comment: You don't need to put the whole file, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example